# Traffic of idle OpenVPN connection

Tags: vpn, traffic

I have a mobile gateway connected to my VPN via OpenVPN and a 2G connection. Now I observe some unexpected traffic (~20MB / day) and wonder where it comes from. While I'm connected to the gateway I see most traffic flowing to my VPN Server (but that might also be my active connection).

So my question is: what is the average traffic caused by OpenVPN when my gateway is connected to the VPN but not sending data through it?

I do **not** have `redirect-gateway def1` enabled.

To monitor real time traffic I used `iftop`; for long time monitoring the OpenWRT on my gateway does not have any of these packages available: `wrtbwmon, vnstat, YAMon, luci_app_statistics, bandwidthd, ntop`

Any hints how to find our where my traffic comes from (IP, Port, Process) in the long term would also help me a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here, You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: Whats consumer-grade? I'm facing a an Industrial LoRaWAN gateway that we connect using a OpenWRT based industrial GSM Modem.

Comment: OpenWRT is off-topic because it runs on consumer-grade devices. What are the network device models? Do the manufacturers offer optional, paid support?

Comment: I'm sure they do, you can find the product (running the OpenWRT) here: https://www.lorixone.io/

Comment: The problem is that the manufacturer of OpenWRT does not offer optional, paid support, a requirement here, nor can I find such an offer for the device you linked.

Answer (score 2):

I've got ~180 KB after one hour with an idle connection - so, depending on the exact OpenVPN version and configuration, 20 MB/day seem about right.

You'll need to monitor the connection on the gateway itself to find out what exactly this traffic is. You should be able to run `tcpdump` on OpenWRT - however, consumer-grade devices are off-topic here.

Comment: see comment above